# How to redirect a url to development environment in Organization Network

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, sonicwall, url-routing

In my organisation we have nearly 100 people but we dont have any dedicated IT Staff to manage our network. We have one of our product running on a domain name http://www.domainkachra.com.

We want if anyone from our organisation try to open URL http://*.domainkachra.com (here * is for wild card sub domain, means any subdomain on domainkachra.com), he should be automatically redirected to http://dev.domainkachra.com/application

We have our own windows based DNS. I am not sure whether we need to implement something on DNS Server or firewall (SonicWal NSA4600) or Developer Machines (Which are nearly 100 machines in our case). Please guide me how we can achieve above mentioned behaviour.

Regards, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it's going to be much easier to change your DNS and web server configurations than to modify 100 developer machines and keep them that way.

1. Set up a webserver that responds to *dev.domainkachra.com*.
2. Set an A record in DNS, with a wildcard name, which resolves to the IP of the webserver in the previous answer
3. Set the VirtualHost to listen on all hostnames for that IP number, and on the bare "/" to send a 302 with a redirect to "/application"